# Already an open data reader associated with this command. How is this possible?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ado.net

I have the following class:

```
public class Data
{
    static public SqlDataReader ExecutSql(string sql)
    {
        var cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, SqlCon.Conn);
        var data = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        return data;
    }
}
```

It's called from an asp.net webpage and I'm getting the error: "There is already an open DataReader associated with this command which must be closed first."

Clearly I'm instantiating a new SqlCommand the line right before I execute the data reader.  I am new to web development (my background is WinForms) but even so I can't comprehend how I can already have an open DataReader associated with a Command that was literally just created??  I could possibly understand if it was a multi-threading sort of issue, but I'm stepping throught the code in the debugger and getting this error.

Someone want to tell me what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you already called this method before ? Your method is returning an SqlDataReader  and i am not sure whether it is being closed properly.As per [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.close.aspx),

> You must explicitly call the Close method when you are through using
>   the SqlDataReader to use the associated SqlConnection for any other
>   purpose.

I would suggest you to read the data from your reader and close the reader and return the new type( a DataTable / DataSet or your custom class filled with properties)

```
using(SqlCommand command =new SqlCommand(sql, SqlCon.Conn))
{
   SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   while (reader.Read())
   {
     //Fill your object and then use that to return
   }
}
```

Comment: Strange, the error message leads you to believe you can only have one SqlDataReader open per Command when it's actually per connection.  Thanks.

Comment: And yeah, your suggestion is exactly what I normally do but this is such a small and simple app that I didn't bother this time.

Answer (score 1):

When exactly are you calling the SqlDataReader ExecutSql(string sql) method? Is it at page load? Because if it is so, then in asp.net page load gets called everytime any event occurs on the page. To prevent this, you could use the following:

```
if(!Page.IsPostBack)
{
    //call SqlDataReader ExecutSql(string sql)
}
```

This would ensure that the above method gets called only once when the page is loading when opened. In case of a post back due to any event, this method would not be called.

Answer (score 0):

You can also enable [MARS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1a7f4f%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) in your connection string: